# Derivation of mean of Student's t-distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

How would you derive the mean of this distribution with a degree of freedom p?
My course writes the distribution as follows: 
[T distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYCmy.png)

Edit: I was trying to proceed with calculus but nothing struck me at all. I didn't have much experience with t-distribution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: "This distribution"? If you want an empirical unbiased estimator of $\mu$, use $\overline{x}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i$. If you want to prove the standardised pdf gives a mean of $0$, use the fact it's an even function. If you want to motivate the Student's $t$-distribution, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Sampling_distribution). It's based on our need to estimate $\sigma^2$ as a random $s^2$, so $\frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{s}$ has a [ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation).

Comment: What have *you* tried to derive the mean?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I couldn't proceed except staring at the pdf..I think Jack M's answer ought to be right.

Comment: I was trying to derive the mean by using calculus.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Have you *looked* at that density function? What is really gained by forcing people to write in their question "I tried integrating it but couldn't at all"?

Comment: @JackM Yes it's a 't' pdf, so? Why are you asking me if I have looked at the question? Can't the mean be derived from definition?  I simply asked the OP what they had tried. The post is closed precisely because no effort was shown on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you define the Student's T-distribution, but for me it's by definition the distribution of the random variable

$$T=\sqrt n \frac {\overline{X_n} - \mu} {\sqrt{\frac 1 {n-1}\sum(X_i-\overline{X_n})^2}}$$

where the $X_i$ are $n$ independent $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ variables. Note that at first glance this seems like a bad definition, since you would think the distribution of $T$ would depend on $\mu$ and $\sigma$. So in order to show that the T-distribution is well-defined in the first place, we need to justify that the distribution of the above expression does not depend on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/337277/143178)). Once we know that, the fact that the mean is $0$ is actually a corollary.

Since $\mu$ and $\sigma$ don't affect the distribution of $T$, we can take $\mu=0$. Now consider the variables $Y_i=-X_i$ and form from them the T-distributed random variable:

$$T'=\sqrt n \frac {\overline{Y_n} - \mu} {\sqrt{\frac 1 {n-1}\sum(Y_i-\overline{Y_n})^2}}$$

But if you replace each $Y_i$ by its definition and work out the algebra, you'll see that in fact $T'=-T$. Thus $T$ and $-T$ have the same distribution, and $\mathbb E(T)=0$.

Comment: Please see the update to the question text.

Comment: A $t$ distributed variable with $n$ degrees of freedom is $T=\frac{X}{\sqrt {Y/n}}$ by definition, where $X$ is standard normal and $Y$ is chi-squared with $n$ degrees of freedom, independent of $X$.

Comment: @user585258 I think it would be easier (and more importantly, make more sense conceptually) to define the Student's T the way I have, and then show that its PDF is what you say. Defining mathematical objects by a complicated formula equal to them is usually a bad way to do things.